What is wrong with this if statement script comparing variable against a number range
I have made a script with if to check for a running timer, but the script sometimes accepts the check and the other time it does not. I do not know why ?
The timer is read and set into a variable, it can be everything within 1s to 59s. depending on which time it was read.
The partial script (the part which matters)
while true; do

ontime=$(systemctl status sshd | grep -Po '(?<=CEST; ).*(?= )')

if [[ "$ontime" == ?[1-59]s ]]  ;then

I run the script, and it accepts then. Then I run it again and it goes to else. It keeps doing this randomly while every script test run is randomly between 1 and 59 seconds. I do not understand this random behaviour, I would expect a consistent then or else.

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

When I run this (having set TZ=Europe/Paris) I get the relative uptime of the sshd service. Right now that's 1 month 14 days. What values are you expecting to see? Please add this to your question

For six months of the year your code will fail. Instead of matching on CEST you should use CES?T. But better would be to go timezone agnostic and use TZ=UTC systemctl... here, matching on UTC

In each half of the if (the then and else sections) write out the value of $ontime so you can see what's been received. For example echo "! Ontime if THEN: ontime=$ontime." >&2

You haven't specified what scripting language or shell you are using, however as far as I know all the common shells that support the [[ ... ]] extended test syntax interpret the RHS of an == operator as a glob-style pattern with the following properties:

? matches any single character
[1-59] matches a single character that collates lexically between 1 and 5 in your locale, or the character 9

If the ontime variable contains a decimal number in the range 1-59, then your test will fail for

any single digit value

any value whose last digit is 0, 6, 7, or 8 1


If you use zsh, you could replace [1-59] with an actual numeric range pattern like <1-59>. In ksh (or bash, when the extglob shell option is set), you could do something like
[[ "$ontime" == @([123456789]|[012345][0123456789])s ]]

to test the single-digit range 1-9 and two-digit range 10-59 separately.
Alternatively, you could use a true numeric expression (( ... )) after removing the s character - in fact, you might want to avoid parsing the human readable systemctl status output altogether, and instead use something like
systemctl show --property=ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic --value sshd 

instead.
See also the somewhat related How to load more than 10 files with range in executable args?.

1 the actual range of characters matched by [1-5] will depend on your locale, but I think it's safe to assume it will contain none of these decimal digits.
If you want to test for

Thanks, this made sense. It works now with: if [[ "$ontime" =~ ^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9])s$ ]]; then     It is a bash script btw

@SunyataNothing If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

sorry, but where is this check mark ?
